# Erro ao recuperar um textarea por jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou com o seguinte problema estou tentando recuperar um textarea de uma div resposta que é clicado para abrir, mas que da erro ao tentar recuperar o textarea por algum motivo não estou conseguindo alguém consegue me ajudar ?

codigos:

javascript

```
    function addEventosRespostas() {
   $('.resposta')

       .on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).children('input').val();
        var texto = $('.resp').children('#texto').val();
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $('.coment').find('.resp').fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $('.resposta').fadeIn("fast");
        });

        $(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp').fadeIn("slow");

        $('.resp').find('input').on("click",function(){

            alert(texto);
//            $.post('swith/viwer.php',{
//                acao: 'responder', id: id},
//            function(){
//                $('.visualizaron').fadeOut('slow');
//            });
           return false; 
        });

        return false;
       });
}
```

html com php

```
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
                        <div class='coment com' >

                                <?php 

                    if($foto == "" || $foto == "uploads/"):
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='".REQUIRE_PATH."/css/boot/icons/thumb.png'></a>";
                    else:
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='{$imx['foto']}'></a>";
                    endif;
                    ?>
                   <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> <?=$nome?> <small>Em:  </small> <?=$date?> <small>As: </small> <?=$hora?></p>

                   <div class="comentando">
                       <p><?=nl2br($comentario)?></p></div>
                       <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder<input type='hidden' value='<?=$big[id] ?>' name='idcoment'>
                       </div>
                       <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
                           <form method='post' name="comentarios">
                               <textarea id="texto"></textarea>  

                               <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque o `.children('#texto')` por `.find('#texto')`. O `#texto` não é filho direto do `.resposta`, mas sim do `.resp`, logo:

```
$(this).siblings('.resp').find('#texto');
```

Como o `.resp` e o `.resposta` estão no mesmo nível use o `siblings`.

---

```js
$('.resposta').on("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).children('input').val();
  var texto = $(this).siblings('.resp').find('#texto').val();


  $(this).text('Ver Digitado');


  $(this).fadeOut("fast");
  $('.coment').find('.resp').fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('.resposta').fadeIn("fast");
  });

  if (texto != '') {
    alert(texto);
  }

  $(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp').fadeIn("slow");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
  <div class='coment com'>
    <div class="comentando">
      <p>
        <?=nl2br($comentario)?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder</div>
    <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
      <form method='post' name="comentarios">
        <textarea id="texto"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: agora teve um erro quando eu abro uma resposta ao invés dele exibir a que escolhi ele abre a ultima mostrada não mostrando o qual eu digitei

Comment: Editei a resposta, utilize o `siblings` para pegar elementos no mesmo nível.

Comment: consegui resolver o problema eu instanciei o formulário e ficou melhor fiz de outra maneira me ajudou muito suas dicas obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O problema ocorre porque você está definindo e atribuindo o valor do textarea a variável "texto" diretamente dentro do listener do clique '.resposta' e nesse momento não há conteúdo no textarea ainda.

Para resolver o problema basta mover o trecho de código da definição da variável texto, para dentro do listener de clique do botão de "respoder".

O Código final ficará da seguinte forma:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.resposta').on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).children('input').val();

    $(this).fadeOut("fast");

    $('.coment').find('.resp').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $('.resposta').fadeIn("fast");
    });

    $(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp').fadeIn("slow");

    $('.resp').find('input').on("click", function() {
      var texto = $('.resp').find('#texto').val();

      alert(texto);
      //            $.post('swith/viwer.php',{
      //                acao: 'responder', id: id},
      //            function(){
      //                $('.visualizaron').fadeOut('slow');
      //            });
      return false;
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
  <div class='coment com'>
    <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> Eu msm <small>Em:  </small> 07-04-2017 <small>As: </small> 17:14:00</p>

    <div class="comentando">
      <p>Este é um exemplo de comentário</p>
    </div>
    <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder<input type='hidden' value='<?=$big[id] ?>' name='idcoment'>
    </div>
    <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
      <form method='post' name="comentarios">
        <textarea id="texto"></textarea>
        <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```